# FileZilla uploads files with 000 permissions

Tags: file-permissions, uploading, filezilla

I've been having problems with FileZilla a few days now. I have a server running on CentOS with Apache etc. And am uploading Wordpress to a new domain on my server. I've done this a million times before and am currently running 3 other properly working Wordpress sites on my server.

However, when I upload the files to the new domain folder all files receive a 000 permissions. Folders get a normal 755. Manually chmodding the files works but I'm not going to chmod 2000 files and figure out which ones need more permissions.

I have no idea why all of the sudden the files have no permissions, I've changed nothing in the way I connect to the server. I connect over SFTP with the same installation of FileZilla I always use.

I'm on OSX 10.10.1 with the most recent version of FileZilla. I have downloaded the most recent .zip with WordPress, have extracted it and am uploading the files by drag and drop.

Comment: What does php etc have to do with filezilla?

Comment: It was one of the tags stackoverflow itself suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in FileZilla 3.10.0-beta3 through 3.10.0.1.

https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=34953

Either upgrade to 3.10.0.2 or later. Or use another SFTP client.

Comment: Awesome, that explains it, it was driving me crazy.